# Get Date from JSONObject

Tags: java, json, mongodb, org.json

I am using org.json to parse JSON string to JSON object, I have a field 'expirationDate' in JSON object and I want it to be parsed into java.util.Date but the JSONObject class has no getDate() method. When I use getString() method, I get an exception, if I use get() method and then invove toString() method, I get a null pointer exception.
I am gettting the JSONs from a mongodb.
So, how do I get java.util.Date from JSONObject ?

My code:

```
JSONArray jUsage = jsonObj.getJSONArray("attribute");
for(int i=0;i<jUsage.length();i++){
    JSONObject eachUsage = jUsage.getJSONObject(i);
    String aa = eachUsage.get("expirationDate").toString();
}
```

My JSON :

```
"attribute": [
    {
        "expirationDate": {
            "$date": "2013-07-09T08:58:57.517Z"
        }
    }
],
```

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so that we can understand the exact problem - right now you're only listing the symptoms.

Comment: 1) Please provide an example JSON of your data and, 2) Source code that you're having issues with.